# Given an array of sub-arrays how to identify the longest set with disjoint elements?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations

I'm looking for an algorithm for a problem I have to solve, I try to give a definition but then I also give an example because I'm not a native speaker and this definition seems to me hostile :)

Given an array of sub-arrays of integers I would like to identify all combinations of sub-arrays of disjoint numbers that have the largest number of elements in them.

Example:
Array of arrays

[[1,2,3],[1,5],[5],[7,8],[1,3,4]]

In this case, the solution provides two equal sets:

[1,2,3],[5],[7,8]

[1,3,4],[5],[7,8]

The sum of the total elements (let's call it size) is 6 and each sub-array contains elements that do not belong to the other sub-arrays

My reasoning for a solution is as follows:

- I calculate all possible combinations of the initial sub-arrays
- I sort these combinations by size in descending order
- I process the various combinations until I find a combination with disjoint elements

This system, which I believe works, has the problem of being intensive; computing all combinations is quite expensive if the number of sub-arrays grows.

1. Is my way of solving correct?
2. Is there a better way to solve the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You're trying to find a [maximum-weight independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Exact_algorithms), where the vertices of the graph are the sublists, there is an edge between two vertices if the corresponding sublists have integers in common, and the weight of a vertex is the number of integers in that sublist.

Comment: ...and the better way is likely to be a MIP solver, though if you have tiny instances, other engineering concerns may take priority.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling quite a bit I asked to ChatGPT and...incredibile, it found the correct solution!
Here's the javascript implementation.

```
function findLargestDisjointSubarrays(arr) {
const n = arr.length
let maxCount = 0
let maxSubarrays = []

// Recursive function to find disjoint subarrays
function dfs(currIndex, currCount, currSubarrays, allMaxSubarrays) {
    // Check if the current combination is disjoint
    const flat = currSubarrays.flat()
    const set = new Set(flat)
    if (flat.length !== set.size) {
        return
    }

    // Update the maximum count and subarrays if necessary
    if (currCount > maxCount) {
        maxCount = currCount
        maxSubarrays = [currSubarrays]
    } else if (currCount === maxCount) {
        maxSubarrays.push(currSubarrays)
    }

    // Continue searching for disjoint subarrays
    for (let i = currIndex; i < n; i++) {
        dfs(i + 1, currCount + arr[i].length, currSubarrays.concat([arr[i]]), allMaxSubarrays)
    }

    // Add the current subarrays to the allMaxSubarrays array if they have the maximum count
    if (currCount === maxCount) {
        allMaxSubarrays.push(currSubarrays)
    }
}

dfs(0, 0, [], [])

return maxCount === 0 ? [] : maxCount === 1 ? arr.map(subarr => [subarr]) : maxSubarrays
```

}